# Create List from comparing two files

Tags: bash

Is there a better way to do this?  I am generating a list of applications installed on my linux system `APPLIST`. Then I want to check if they are in the `WHITELIST` of allowed apps. If not print them into another file.  I quickly came up with what I have below but was wondering if I could do this more efficiently than a loop like this.

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '[%{NAME}\n]' > ${APPLIST}    
while read app; do
    grep -R "${app}" ${WHITELIST} > /dev/null 2>&1 || echo ${app} >> ${TMPLIST}
done < ${APPLIST}
```

When done whatever wasn't in white list is now in `TMPLIST` file.

I was trying to use this with no luck:

```
diff --changed-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format='' ${WHITELIST} ${APPLIST} > ${TMPLIST}
```

Comment: Store the lists in sorted order, then run `diff` on them?

Answer (score 0):

To build the first list use `sort`

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '[%{NAME}\n]' | sort > ${APPLIST}
```

Then make sure your whitelist is sorted as well, and run `diff` on them for the result.

```
diff ${APPLIST} ${WHITELIST} > ${TMPLIST}
```

**EDIT**

I realize my original answer doesn't produce the desired list of just package names, but a typical `diff` format with *>, <* characters and so forth. Did a little digging and found [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/135171/listing-lines-from-just-one-file-in-diff) on Superuser, very similar to your problem.

Turns out your problem can be solved entirely with `diff` (assuming sorted lists). So borrowing that subshell `sort` magic from @rob mayoff and the `diff` flags from the Superuser thread, here's your two-liner `diff` solution

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '[%{NAME}\n]' | sort > ${APPLIST}
diff --changed-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format='' ${APPLIST} <(sort ${WHITELIST}) > ${TMPLIST}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `join` command can take two sorted lists and print the elements that are in one list but not in the other.

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '[%{NAME}\n]' | sort > ${APPLIST}
join -v 1 ${APPLIST} <(sort ${WHITELIST}) > ${TMPLIST}
```